# Want my masked url to show navigation path past .com

Tags: url

I have a vanity URL that is forwarding to a masked destination URL. But when users navigate the site the URL never changes. For example when they click to a blog entry they still see the vanity url. I want them to be able to see the masked url but everything that would be the blog url path afther the .com/ as well. So they would see www.vanityurl.com/blog-entry-they-just-clicked. What is the term for doing this and can help provide instructions?

EDIT - SOLVED: I pointed the DNS of the vanity URL at my host IP and then created and alias in my CPanel and since the site is a Wordpress site I told it to install using the alias as the URL. Now when I navigate all the urls are unique and include the vanity URL and that is the result I wanted

**More info as requested:**

**What have you tried?**

*I tried changing the display URL at the post level. I researched URL rewriting. I am hesitant to try much of anything until I can confirm what exactly I should be trying so I know I am trying to do something that can achieve the result I am looking for. Not asking anyone to do it for me, just proper advice. Help me fish :)*

I did read about using a reverse proxy.

**As well, you could end up with a duplicate content issue.**

The vanity URL is a temporary redirect and doesn't have any content on it. But I wouldn't want a duplicate content issue.

**Normally, I think I would be using a proxy.**

*I will look into that if that can solve it*

**Are both sites on the same server? Can you explain more about the other domain name?**

*No, the other domain is on it's own server. It is a domain that I have hosting associated with and I bought the vanity URL without hosting. I don't want to pay for two hosting accounts (it's basic hosting). Ideally, I should just add hosting to the vanity URL or transfer the vanity domain over to the Godaddy account that has hosting. I can do all that but I really want to share my site with a few people but can't because I don't want to expose the destination URL or for people to not be able to see vanityurl.com/blog-address in the case that they wanted to share a post.*

**For example, do you care that it shows up in search or that users use it for your site?**

*I don't care so much that the destination URL would show up in search results. Those would be the only people who would see that URL. Anyone else would be given the vanity URL. Basically, the destination URL is meant to eventually be a professional showcase for my resume, blog etc. I want to use other directories to develop other sites/blogs/examples of projects with so the site as a whole is a directory of projects. However or certain projects who's purpose is in this case to be a music review blog I want to use the vanity URL to build the audience with but still have the ability for the destination URL to serve as the link to the project itself anytime that it is made visible through the destination url. In short, the vanity URL is meant for marketing the project that I want to live at the destination URL for the purpose of housing all of my projects under one roof. I guess I am going about it the wrong/long way when I should just upgrade my hosting, or get it's own hosting and I should just wait until I have that to surface the site to anyone.*

Comment: What have you tried? As well, you could end up with a duplicate content issue. Normally, I think I would be using a proxy. Are both sites on the same server? Can you explain more about the other domain name? For example, do you care that it shows up in search or that users use it for your site?

Comment: I updated the question. However, barring all the questions about whether or not what I am trying to do is best practice or not back to my question. Is it possible to ensure that vanityurl.com/blog-path can be displayed to visitors navigating the site?

Comment: Great detail!! Thanks! It gives us the scenario clearly. I am retired and I do not know current hosting products and I suspect there is a simple answer for you. I am an ex-commercial provider and web host. Personally, I would be using a proxy server/router. I am sure there are ways that this can be done easily for you. But I would have to leave it to our other experts. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks. I solved it and yes it was something simple. I pointed the DNS of the vanity URL at my host IP and then created and alias in my CPanel and  since the site is a wordpress site I told it to install using the alias as the URL. Now when I navigate all the urls are unique and include the vanity URL.

Comment: Good!! Now make sure you use canonical tags to avoid duplicate content issues. Here is the Google link: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en